# Tomcat JNDI datasource set own database password

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, datasource, jndi

Currently my system running an external JNDI connection as below:

in my context.xml:

```
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name="jdbc/sql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" 
maxWait="10000" username="sa" password="sa" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\sqlexpress:1433;databaseName=Agent_DB">                 
</Context>
```

my java code:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/sql");          
if (envContext == null) throw new Exception("Error: No Context");
if (ds == null) throw new Exception("Error: No DataSource");
if (ds != null) conn = ds.getConnection();`
```

as you see the password to connect to DB already set in my context.xml. is there any way i could set the database password in my java code? the reason being is due to security issue, the password has to be encrypted so i need to decrypt it in my Java code in order to getConnection().

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, just leave it out of context.xml and use `DataSource.getConnection(username, password).`

Comment: could you please share with me how could it be if i would just use DataSource.getConnection(username, password)?